PhpOffice\PhpWord 1.2.0 - TemplateProcessor add numeric list item dont work
if (!empty($params['responsibilitiesItems'])) {
    $cnt = count($params['responsibilitiesItems']);
    $templateProcessor->cloneBlock('responsibilitiesItems', $cnt, true, true);
    $section = new Section($cnt);

    foreach ($params['responsibilitiesItems'] as $responsibilitiesItem) {
        $section->addListItem($responsibilitiesItem, 0, ['italic' => true, 'color' => 'red'], ListItem::TYPE_NUMBER);
    }

    $i = 0;
    foreach ($section->getElements() as $getElement) {
        $i++;
        $templateProcessor->setComplexValue("responsibilitiesItem#{$i}", $getElement);
    }
}

As result i have corrupt php word file, if open this file in openoffice i got empty field in list possition.
Php word template contains:
${responsibilitiesItems}
${responsibilitiesItems}
${/responsibilitiesItems}


I found solution right now, need extends TemplateProcessor class function setComplexValue and change line:
$this->replaceXmlBlock($search, $xmlWriter->getData(), 'w:r');

On
$this->replaceXmlBlock($search, $xmlWriter->getData());

Block type must be default w:p...
